# How can I fit a tree graph into a grid?

Tags: procedural-generation, tree, maze

I have a tree graph that I'd like to fit into a grid, the result being a grid-based maze that adheres to the tree graph. Are there any good maze algorithms that are able to start with a known structure?

Here's a crude example:

[image]

The child nodes do not have to be immediately adjacent to their parent in the grid, but must maintain the same reachability. This is reflected in the black "dummy" node in the image.

The basic concept is to build a node tree reflecting the "logic" of a space, then building a reasonably compact, grid-based "maze" that maintains that logic.

Comment: This is an interesting question that I haven't seen before. You'll probably get better answers on cs.stackexchange.com or even cstheory.stackexchange.com

Comment: Concise answer: No, you can't, unless many nodes in the tree graph have only one branch or less. The space required for tree graph grows exponentially. But the space grows geometrically in grid. It's like `(n^k)` vs `k^2`.

Comment: Mangata: I think it's safe to presume in this context that the grid is either unbounded/grows appropriately as we place nodes, or that the first step of our algorithm pre-sizes the grid large enough to fit the tree with at least high probability, even if that means making the grid dimensions disproportionately large compared to the tree depth.

Comment: I mean, This problem arises if there are similar restrictions like parent and child nodes must be adjacent in the grids. Maybe i'm wrong because I noticed that there is a ‘fake’ node in the example graph of the post.

Comment: For general trees on a square grid the answer is no, as any tree with more than 4 edges to a node will not map. However, I think it works with modifications. First, you need to 'split' nodes w/ too many edges. For instance, say you have node A with edges to B,C,D,E,F. A could be split A1 & A2 such that A1 connects to A2,B,C,D and A1 connects to A1,E,F. Reachability is the same & distance is preserved provided that edges between split nodes have a distance of 1. And as sort of mention, you either need to allow for dummy nodes or you need to allow edges to span across more than one cell.

Comment: For good answers here on GDSE, it would help if you edited to add details about the game design context for the problem so we could better understand which constraints are hard & which are flexible. I see several possible options in my graph drawing text, but without more info, I don't know which to recommend.

Comment: @Mangata You are correct about the "fake" node. I've clarified the post.

Comment: @Pikalek Reachability is more important than adjacency, yes. Splitting of nodes would be totally acceptable.

Comment: With the goal of minimizing the number of dummy nodes it sounds rather like a hard (not even fully unsolvable?) programming contest problem than anything that you would an existing solver for in the wild.

Comment: The most promising thing I've found so far is something on the [Biedl & Kant orthogonal drawing algorithm](https://i11www.iti.kit.edu/_media/teaching/winter2018/graphvis/graphvis-ws18-v9.pdf). It's long & I haven't had time to see if it can be distilled into an answer.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot fit a tree graph into a 2d grid because of one simple reason - one vertice can have 8+ connections in the 2d grid you have only 8 bordered cells. Even if you limit the nodes connection to for example only a maximum of 2. You will shortly get dead end situations very fast.

Comment: See the comment thread above where workarounds for these problems have already been proposed.

Comment: So you think my answer is not correct can you explain why? And why nobody post the answer this problem have no solution. It can only have solution if you hard limit input tree. Who need such solution with such limitation?